# Can't plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, julia-plots

I am currently reading a book ([BRML](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/textbook/200620.pdf)) which has a demo (earthquake demo, exercise 1.22), which is written in Julia. I have never used Julia (although used Python and other languages quite extensively) before so I'm a complete noob.

What exactly does the line `plot(x,y,".")` do in the following code:

```
Pkg.add("Pkg")
using Pkg
Pkg.add("PyPlot")

S=5000 # number of points on the spiral
x=zeros(S); y=zeros(S)
for s=1:S
    theta=50*2*pi*s/S;  r=s/S
    x[s]=r*cos(theta); y[s]=r*sin(theta)
end
plot(x,y,".")
```

I understand everything that is done before that, however I'm not sure what that specific line does. The reason I can't see for myself is because when I'm trying to run it on an online [Julia compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_julia_online.php), I get the following error:

```
INFO: Initializing package repository /home/cg/root/4655378/.julia/v0.6
INFO: Cloning METADATA from https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
ERROR: LoadError: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:Net, curl error: Could not resolve host: github.com
)
Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at ./libgit2/error.jl:99 [inlined]
 [2] clone(::String, ::String, ::Base.LibGit2.CloneOptions) at ./libgit2/repository.jl:276
 [3] #clone#100(::String, ::Bool, ::Ptr{Void}, ::Nullable{Base.LibGit2.AbstractCredentials}, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at ./libgit2/libgit2.jl:562
 [4] (::Base.LibGit2.#kw##clone)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.LibGit2.#clone, ::String, ::String) at ./<missing>:0
 [5] (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##8#10{String,String})() at ./pkg/dir.jl:55
 [6] cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##8#10{String,String}, ::String) at ./file.jl:70
 [7] init(::String, ::String) at ./pkg/dir.jl:53
 [8] #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at ./pkg/dir.jl:28
 [9] add(::String) at ./pkg/pkg.jl:117
while loading /home/cg/root/4655378/main.jl, in expression starting on line 1
```

Comment: Online compilers/interpreters are usually restricted to the standard library, so trying to install packages will fail. Moreover, this website is using version 0.6 of Julia, which is *very* outdated. replit has one for version 1.3.1 which is very close to the current version 1.6.3, but again, you can't install packages. Instead, you should download Julia, install the package, experiment with some code, and read the package's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the third line indicates, the book is using the `PyPlot` package, which is basically a [Julia wrapper around](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/backends/#%5BPyPlot%5D(https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl)) Python's `pyplot`.

So, we could refer to [pyplot's documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html) to figure out how that line of code works. But as mentioned in that page, `pyplot` is trying to emulate MATLAB's `plot` function, and for this case their [help page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) is easier to navigate. As mentioned there,

> plot(X,Y) creates a 2-D line plot of the data in Y versus the corresponding values in X.

and `plot(X,Y,LineSpec)` in addition "creates the plot using the specified line style, marker, and color." Clicking on LineSpec, we can see in the second table that `'.'` is one of the markers, with description `Point` and the resulting marker a black filled dot.

So: **`plot(x,y,".")` creates a plot with dots as markers at the points specified by the x- and y-coordinates**. [image: dot-markered plot]

We could also try one of the other markers, for eg. `plot(x,y,"+")` creates this instead:
[image]

where if you look carefully, you can see that the points are marked by `+` signs instead.